# Unresolved external symbol, multiple projects, Visual C++ linker error?

Tags: c, reference, linker, project

I have two projects, my own and a framework I'm trying to use. The projects are located in different directories, but both are added to my solution and I've got all references "working" (according to the compiler(?) and intellisense) by adding the framework location to additional paths for my own project.

I'm able to create a variable of a type defined in the framework, but when I add a function call to one of the functions in the framework I get "unresolved external symbol _GMI_Image_create.

Is there something more I have to do to make the linker understand where to find GMI_Image_create? Why can I create my function but not call the function?

I can't really paste any large parts of the code since it's company property but I hope I've been specific enough!

Both projects are written in C, not sure if the framework uses anything written in C++ though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the .lib of the frame work to your projects that reference them.  There is an additonal include directive under the linker setting and a libs directory.  You need both to get the linker to find the library.

Comment: Ok so I have  to compile the framework project to a .lib? I can't just reference the uncompiled framework code somehow?

Comment: Only if all the code is in the headder files. You could add all the files to your project and the linker could then find all the object files, but don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Go Project>C/C++>Advanced>Compile As then change to "compile as c /TC"

Comment: or encapsulate with extern "C"{ ... }